このサイトは衰退しています
このサイト、「スタック・オーバーフロー」ことStack Overflow日本語版は衰退しています。その事実を報告・確認したいと思います。（この投稿は質問では有りませんが、感想や指摘など有れば、回答やコメントをお寄せ下さい。）
日本語版の状況
投稿数は下落傾向です
下の図は、月毎に見た投稿数のグラフです。一般公開の翌月から先月までを集計しました。概ね下落傾向が続いています。
日本語版の投稿数（月毎集計）: 2015-01-01 〜 2024-06-30 (クエリ)

回答が質問より少なくなりました
一般に賑わっている質問サイトは、回答が質問より多い傾向に有ります。しかし、このサイトでは既に逆転しています。
例えば先月は、

質問: 81
回答: 57

です。
投稿の絶対数が少ないです
このサイトの目的からすると、「少ないメンバー間で緩やかな交流が続く」といったことにはなりません。存続に必要な最低限の投稿数というものが、どこかに有ります。その境を下回る（あるいは既に下回った）可能性が有ります。
例:

Rubyに関する投稿: 3月〜4月の間、0 でした。
SQLに関する投稿: 3月〜6月の間、0 でした。


以上が日本語版の状況です。客観的に見て衰退しており、限界が近いと考えます。
英語版の状況
参考のため英語版も見てみます。公開からしばらくの勢いはとても大きなものでした。これは日本語版とまったく違います。しかし、現在は日本語版と同じく下落傾向です。
下記2点が日本語版と違い、まだ限界は来ていないと考えます。

回答: まだギリギリ、質問と同じ程度の回答が有ります。
絶対数: 先月は投稿が10万を下回ったとは言え、万単位です。

英語語版の投稿数（月毎集計）: 2008-08-01 〜 2024-06-30 (クエリ)


stackoverflow に限らずネット Q&A 掲示板自体が衰退しているんだと思います。そういうご時世だし、仕方ないね。で、衰退しているからどうしたいんですか？　盛り上げたい？　安全安心な撤退方法を探りたい？　それともほかの何か？

@774RR どうしたいかは、皆さんにうかがおうと思っています。

この共同創業者のブログ記事を見ると、投稿数は最重要なKPI・KGIでは無いようにも見えます。結局何が数値的な指標になるかは読み取れませんが。
The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions
Encyclopedia Stack Exchange
最初の記事からいくつか抜粋すると、この辺が特徴的だと思われます。

Oh look, my PC is freezing. Should I use SELECT *? Oh, and, how can I host a server from home?
ああ、PC がフリーズしてしまいました。SELECT * を使うべきでしょうか? ところで、自宅からサーバーをホストするにはどうすればいいでしょうか?
Really, people, do you want to be answering these same questions ten years from now? How about when you're 65? That doesn't sound so appealing now, does it?
皆さん、本当に、10年後に同じ質問に答えたいですか？65歳になったらどうですか？今はあまり魅力的に聞こえませんよね？



Otherwise, the basic questions would just get asked again and again, and the old timers would grow bored and leave. The quality of the newsgroup would then deteriorate to approximately the level you would expect if seventh-graders were left to themselves, in other words, Lord of the Flies.
そうでなければ、基本的な質問が何度も繰り返され、古参メンバーは飽きて去ってしまうでしょう。そうなると、ニュースグループの質は、7 年生を放っておいた場合に予想されるレベル、つまり「蝿の王」のレベルにまで低下するでしょう。



When you see a question that seems like it might reflect a common problem, don't just answer it to get a few points. That doesn't make the Internet any better. Instead, help us build up a library of canonical questions and answers that are more generic versions of the same question, and then start closing all the exact duplicates.
一般的な問題を反映していると思われる質問を見つけたら、ポイントを稼ぐためだけに回答しないでください。それではインターネットは良くなりません。代わりに、同じ質問のより一般的なバージョンである標準的な質問と回答のライブラリの構築に協力し、その後、まったく同じ重複をすべて閉じ始めてください。


Don't answer questions that have already been answered elsewhere.
すでに他の場所で回答されている質問には答えないでください。


If you're going to close a user's question as a duplicate, it has to be a real duplicate.
ユーザーの質問を重複として閉じる場合は、本当に重複している必要があります。


It is OK to edit a question to make it more general.
質問を編集して、より一般的なものにすることは問題ありません。


Help us build a great library of canonical answers.
標準的な回答の素晴らしいライブラリの構築にご協力ください。


そうは言っても774RRさんがコメントしているように、「ネット Q&A 掲示板自体が衰退している」のかもしれませんが、肯定的に見ればこのサイトの目標が達成されつつある(ただし中途半端な)成果とも考えられます。
日本語ではこちらヘルプのツアー記事にある以下の記述です。

目標は、プログラミングに関するあらゆる質問の詳細な回答集をみんなで作り上げること。ぜひあなたの力を貸してください。

中途半端というのは、サイトの状況では「あらゆる質問」とは言い難い感じですし、すべてが「詳細な回答」とも言えないでしょう。
しかし長年の記事の積み重ねによって知識・経験は蓄積されていると思われますし、それによってサイトを検索すれば疑問や問題に対する回答や手掛かりが見つかることが多いので、新たな質問を出す機会も減ったということでしょう。
結局は同じ傾向かもしれませんが、質問・回答数ではなくページビューの統計があるならどんなものか気になりますね。

それは例えばWindows11のCopilotといった生成AIツールなどでプログラミングの質問を行った際に、根拠や参考になる詳細情報にこのサイトの記事が出てくるときもある(多い？)ことでわかるでしょう。
そういう意味で日本語/英語サイト共に2023年から質問・回答数の減少が加速している様にも見えるのは生成AIツールの影響かもしれません。
ただしStackOverflowが正式に連携することにしたのは今年の春からのようですが、別にQ&Aサイトやプログラミングの知識・経験・ノウハウ等を扱っているのはここだけでは無いので他で情報が得られればここへの質問は減るでしょう。
API Partnership with Stack Overflow
OpenAIとプログラミングQ&Aサイトが協業　ChatGPTから参照可能に
他にはこんな変化(or傾向)があるような気がしないでもない程度。単に流行とか時期的な物かもしれませんが。

typo原因の質問は減った気がする
知識0から始めて新しい項目に手を出すたび質問しているような人も減った気がする
競技プログラミング関連の質問は減った気がする
学習途上と思われる人の質問はまだそこそこ有る気がする
開発元リポジトリのIssuesとか商品・製品・サービスの提供元に聞けば良いのにと思うような質問は減った気がしないでもないが、気のせいかもしれない
XY問題的な質問や何故それをその環境でやろうとしているのか？という感想の出る質問はまだ残っている気がする
それと類似して誰が作っている/使っているんだろう？というようなマイナーなライブラリとか機能の使い方といった質問はまだ残っている気がする


日本でStackOverflowと直接的に対比されるQ&Aサイトは、今では teratail くらいでしょうが、一応他にも性質の少しづつ違う色々なサイトがあります。 Qiitaは主に自由な記事投稿サイトですが質問のタブが出来て件数も多いらしいですね。
【2024年版】プログラミング質問サイトおすすめ11選！質問の仕方も紹介
駆け出しエンジニアにおすすめのQ&Aサイトまとめ
teratailにおける質問・回答・ページビューの統計データが入手できるならば、それと比較してみると面白いかもしれませんね。
ちなみに最近見たらteratailでは「質問カテゴリー」という分類が出来ていて、「すべて」「Q&A」「意見交換」という選択がありました。
「意見交換」はStackOverflowが非推奨にしている分野を突いて取り入れる面白い選択肢です。
公式ブログの記事を遡ってみたら2023年1月にリリースされたようで意外と時間が経っていますね。ただあまり流行ってはいないようですが。
Qiitaの質問タブにも「意見交換」があったので同様にStackOverflowとの差別化が意識されているのでしょう。
